# How to add marqee to TextView in android using small text

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, marquee

I would like to apply Marquee feature to TextView in my application and i've successfully implemented it. Here is the code that i have used.

`<TextView
            android:id="@+id/latest_notification"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />`

and in fragment

```
        mLatestNotification = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.latest_notification);
    mLatestNotification.setSelected(true);
    mLatestNotification
            .setText("Scrollable textScrollable textScrollable textScrollable textScrollable text Scrollable text");
```

Now my question is if i assign small text to TextView then marquee feature is not working. Is there way that i can apply marquee for small text as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code I've grabbed it from my project

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    android:textColor="#757575" />
```

Comment: It only works when i give large text. Is there a way to do it for small texts as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

It only works when text size is large.